# Access python script from one project to another

Tags: django, python-2.7

```
Main folder
   |-project1
   |-project2
```

I have the above structure for django projects. 
When I am in project1 in a script i used os.chdir(to_project2) to project 2 
I want to access project2's settings.py and fetch some attributes. Is it possible?

Comment: So you just need some values from the `settings.py` of the second project? Or you need your `models` and other django stuff as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
#You need to point your directory.[Ex: project2]
import os 
os.chdir(project2 )
cd = os.getcwd() 

# print the current directory 
print("Current directory:", cwd)

#For Access the Django setting attributes
import django
from django.conf import settings
```

All of  those aforementioned  code you may use from one of your python file: something.py